# Javascript not working in Google Chrome Browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I've put up a code for commenting box on my html file for the visitors to comment on something in my website, and the code is provided from a website that offers it for free.
The problem is, the commenting box is visible and functions perfectly on Internet Explorer, but in Google Chrome Browser, or FireFox Browser, the commenting box doesn't even appear on the screen. When i view source by right-clicking, the code is still there, but does not show on the screen, and I think something is wrong with the code.
I have tried to fix this myself, and I could not figure this out alone.

Here is the code that was provided from the free commenting box website.

```
<div class="js-kit-comments" backwards="yes" paginate="10"></div>
<script src="http://js-kit.com/comments.js"></script>
```

I wish i could provide more code, but honestly, this is basically it.

I really hope you guys can help me out on this one. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The big js code isn't made to be compatible.

First line :

```
try { if(!window.JSK$EPB && navigator.appVersion.match(/[345]\.[.0-9 ]+Safari/)) {
```

This is not the task of SO to adapt and/or debug a big proprietary script in the blind.

Comment: is there any way to make this code compatible to chrome browser ? or is it just not possible ?